# Smartsheet and Jira with Data Tracker

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, smartsheet-api

I'm stuck setting up a Jira instance with Smartsheet.

I've followed the [Tutorial](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/Smartsheet-Data-Tracker) and I've got to the point where I've got the logs shown below and I'm stuck to know where to go next in trying to get it to work!  *(I am using python 2.7.6.)*

I believe it could be something with connecting to the Jira API and getting a JSON string returned. Tried everything any now I'm out of ideas - I'm hoping you guys can help me out!

Log:

> ***Smartsheet Data Tracker Utility Started: 2014-08-05 14:57:15
>       2014-08-05 14:57:15,795 - utils.config - INFO - {u'sheetColumn': u'Issue ID', u'sourceKey': u'key'}
>       2014-08-05 14:57:16,796 - utils.config - INFO - Updating sheet: Test of SmartSheet / Jira Project
>       2014-08-05 14:57:16,796 - utils.config - INFO - Source: jiraIssueAPI
>       2014-08-05 14:57:16,796 - utils.config - INFO - ===Smartsheet Data Tracker Utility Completed: 2014-08-05 14:57:16

Any help will me much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: On first blush, it looks like your sheet may not have any data in the 'Issue ID' column. Data Tracker uses values from lookupMapping.sheetColumn, in this case the 'Issue ID' column, to search for matching issues in Jira. Are your Jira ids in the 'Issue ID' column in your sheet? For instance, I might have the value 'DEMO-1102' in my Issue ID column. Data Tracker would take that value and search your Jira projects for that issue. Are your Jira issue ids in the 'Issue ID' column in your sheet?

Comment: Yeah spot on, was questioning why it was working! Was targeting the wrong smartsheet with no data in. Found it by before reading thi but thanks very much for the help! I'm now trying to run a script to take edits in Smartsheet and put them back into Jira, any recommendations on where to look? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Bidirectional syncing gets a little more tricky. One option to explore would be to check the modifiedAt value on the Smartsheet row, and compare it to the updated value for the Jira Issue. Which ever date is later "wins"

Comment: I considered that problem. I'm surprised that someone hasnt ammended the smartsheet Data Tracker to do it already. I'm considering having two scripts. One Jira Get, the other Jira Push. I'm a complete Python novice (started early this week) but I've managed so far to get ID's and Fields to update into an array and too check if the issues exists in Jira already. I'm now trying to match the fields between both APIs using the mappings file. Any suggestions on how you would recommend this would be great! Thanks